# How to change the color of * in inputTextField richfaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I want to change the color of star to red in below inputtextfield

```
<h:outputText   value="D.O.J. *" required="true" styleClass="formLabelswidth25"/>
```

here the styleclas is for inputText.

how can I do it

Answer (score 1):

What do you need JSF components for? Just do it in a plain old HTML manner:

```
<span class="normal-text">D.O.J.</span><span class="color-text">*</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:outputText   value="D.O.J. *" required="true" styleClass="formLabelswidth25"/>
```

Replace it with

```
  <h:outputText   value="D.O.J." required="true" styleClass="formLabelswidth25"/>
  <font  size="2" color="red">
    <h:outputText value="*" />
  </font>
```